# Solving Canon PIXMA MP190 E27 error

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, printer, troubleshooting

Suddenly our printer -- Canon PIXMA MP190 -- stopped working and it shows `E27` (`E ... 2 ... 7`) error. From what I saw, this means *Ink Absorber is Full*.

Most of search results recommend to [put the printer in service mode and to use a software resetter](http://mariostroger.blogspot.ro/2012/04/canon-mp1908-error-e27-ink-absorber-is.html).

I am on a Linux machine, but if the fix requires a Windows machine, I have access to one and I can connect the printer to it.

---

What I tried:

1. I tried to reset the printer using a software. That software doesn't recognize the printer...
2. I opened the printer and cleaned up the things there. A lot of ink was wasted on absorbers. I cleaned them up and put all the things together back.

   Same error appears after this clean up.

---

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: The ink absorber full message is about a mechanical problem, not something you simply reset.  Inkjets waste a lot of ink priming the head and cleaning it.  It goes into an absorbent material.  When that fills up, the pad generally needs to be replaced or the waste ink has nowhere to go and you will have a mess (or the printer is designed to stop working until you fix it).  After you replace the pad, you reset the printer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can find, you can do this after disconnecting power and cleaning the printer.

1. Press and hold the "Power" button and reconnect the power cord.
2. When the printer comes on, release the button.
3. Wait five seconds and push the "Power" button again.

This resets the printer's internal memory and overrides the "Ink Absorber Full" error code.

---

Another posting suggests the following to manually reset it.

**Manual Reset for Canon Pixma MPC190 Printers**

1. Enter the service mode SERVICE MODE - pressing buttons Menu, Copy,
   Scan, Copy, Copy
2. Choose TEST MODE.
3. Select 8 PRINTER TEST TEST MODE.
4. Choose 3, EEPROM CLEAR
5. Select 0, INK COUNT
6. Press the Set button.
7. Click Stop / Reset button (return to item 3), and again press the ON
   / OFF

Comment: Interesting! After following *Power* button trick I get `E22` error.  Looks like something happened there. :-) How can I fix that? From what I see it's `Carriage error`.

Comment: Don't know. Typically that is caused by something blocking the carriage. Make sure you've put everything back after cleaning it.

Comment: My brother did fix the issue using some black magic by resetting the printer using Windows... It worked for a while and then it showed other wierd errors. I think it was pretty much what you recommended, but the final fix was buying a new printer. :-)